# Rock climbing higher and faster

Tags: mathematics, optimization

The Olympic rock climbing competition has 20 climbers. Each climber competes in 3 separate events, where they rank from 1st to 20th. The final score of a climber is the product of their rankings from the 3 events, where lower is better. For example, if a climber finishes 5th, 3rd and 10th then their final score will be $5∗3∗10=150$.

Now I have two questions. You can answer one or both:

1. What is the most number of climbers that can tie on the same score?
2. What is the longest sequence of consecutive scores possible? A consecutive sequence is one where each successive term increases by 1, such as $x, x+1, x+2, \ldots, x+N$.

Comment: Hmmm looks like people don't like this puzzle? The solutions are actually quite interesting.

Answer (score 5):

What is the most number of climbers that can tie on the same score?

> 12, with a score of 720:
>
>  Three climbers with score of 3 * 15 * 16
>  Three climbers with score of 4 * 9 * 20
>  Three climbers with score of 5 * 8 * 18
>  Three climbers with score of 6 * 10 * 12

Proof that this is maximal:

> The product of all players' scores is $20!^3=2^{54}\cdot3^{24}\cdot5^{12}\cdot7^6\cdot11^3\cdot13^3\cdot17^3\cdot19^3$
>
>  Any score with a prime factor greater than five can occur at most six times.
>
>  Scores with a factor of five can occur at most 12 times, as in the solution shown.
>
>  Scores that only have prime factors less than five must be the product of three numbers in $\{1,2,3,4,6,8,9,12,16,18\}$ and as there are only ten of these, there cannot be more than ten climbers with such scores. (The limit in this case is actually 9 climbers with a score of 144)

Answer (score 3):

Question 1

> 12 people is the maximum, which can only be reached with scores of 240 360 or 720.

> The small prime factor counts of all the scores, i.e. 20!^3 are:
>  7: 6
>  5: 12
>  3: 24
>  2: a lot
>  So if we want to have more than 6 people we cannot use 7 (or higher)
>  Variation in the prime factors is important, so we probably need a factor 5 and 2 factor 3s
>  Taking this into account it makes sense to try 12 people
>  This limit our option since all multiples of 3 and 5 are needed, and in addition the factors of 2 need to be a multiple of 12
>
>  numbers used: from each event 3,5,6,9,10,12,15,18,20,2^a,2^b,2^c
>  using the highest factors of 2 : 4,8,16 exclusively allows a tying score of 720
>  half that score may also be possible using 111444888, 112244888 or something similar as factors of 2

> option 720
>  Distributing the multiples of 5 and some trying easily give the following options
>  A: 5-9-16,10-4-18,15-6-8,20-3-12
>  B: 5-8-18,10-6-12,15-3-16,20-4-9
>  Rotating A or B over the events gives 2 solutions
>  I did not find more solution

> option 360
>  Distributing the multiples of 5 and some trying easily give the following options without 2s
>  A: 5-8-9,10-3-12,15-4-6,20-1-18
>  B: 5-6-12,10-4-9,15-3-8,20-1-18
>  Rotating A or B over the events gives 2 solutions
>  However, there are more solutions e.g.
>  C: 5-6-12,10-2-18,15-3-8,20-2-9  ,combined with 2 rotated B

> If we do not use factor 5 , we cannot use 15 and thus have less than 24 factor 3s
>  Thus we have only one factor 3 per person available if aiming for at least 12 persons, meaning each person scores at least 2 times a power of 2
>  There are only 15 of those, less than the 24 needed.
>  This leaves us with only one other option-group 2^n*15:
>  Then:
>  12 spots are used for multiples of 5
>  9 additional spots are used for multiples of 3: 3, 6 and 12 since 9 and 18 cannot be used
>  This means all 15 powers of 2 must be used
>  Using all of {1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,12,15,16,20} 3 times turns out to yield valid results:
>  option 240
>  A: 5-6-8, 10-2-12, 15-1-16, 20-3-4
>  B: 5-3-16, 10-4-6, 15-2-8,  20-1-12
>  C: 5-4-12, 10-3-8, 15-1-16, 20-2-6
>  Rotating A, B or C over the events gives 3 solutions

Comment: Nice work. After finding and posting the my solution (your 720-B), I wrote some code to find other solutions. There are a total of 8 solutions for 720. There are 13 solutions for 240. And there are 23 solutions for 360, including one in which all triplets are distinct.

Comment: Well done! This is the correct answer for part 1.

Comment: @DanielMathias Wow, thx, that is more than I expected. I did add my answer to show that there are more optimal solutions than one / than yours, but clearly I am far from complete. Even if mine had been complete, I would find your to the point answer better than my wall of text though.

Answer (score 1):

## Possible answer to #1

I think the answer to the first question might be:

> 9 people.

> If three people come 5th, 6th and 12th, three come 4th, 9th and 10th, and three come first, 18th and 20th, 9 people are tied at a score of 360.

This is in theory - After a lot  of trial-and-error I can't come  up with anything better.

Update: According to the OP it's possible to do better.

## Proven answer to #2

> 5.
>
>  There are a couple of candidates for ranges of numbers with length >4:
>  - 1-22
>  - 24-28
>  - 32-36
>  - 48-52
>  The range 24-28 can be created using the following:
>  - 24 - 6 * 4 * 1
>  - 25 - 5 * 5 * 1
>  - 26 - 13 * 2 * 1
>  - 27 - 3 * 3 * 3
>  - 28 - 2 * 2 * 7
>  And there are no possivle ranges larger than length 5 aside from within 1-22.
>  But note that we can only use 3 1s. This means we can only have at most one prime, and at most three semiprimes, one if we have a prime.
>  We can express numbers with >2 prime factors for free, as long as we have enough 2s.
>  So if we want a range of length 6, it must have either three semiprimes and three numbers with >2 prime factors, or a prime, a semiprime, and four numbers with >2 prime factors.
>  There are only four numbers with >2 prime factors within 1-22: 12, 16, 18, and 20.
>  Therefore, the second is impossible, as these are not within a range of 6.
>  16, 18 and 20 are within a range of 6, but any range containing them contains the two primes 17 and 19, which we can't have.
>  Therefore, the most consecutive scores you can get is 5.

99%  sure this is correct, let me know if I've made a mistake with my proof here.

Comment: Please hide your answer. You can do better for #1.

Comment: You got the correct answer for #2, but there are more solutions